# d3 marklogic rest api

Tags: json, rest, d3.js, marklogic

I am using D3 for a tree visualisation. I would like to draw the data from a marklogic rest API. However when I add the URL the visualisation fails. The URL has been tested in Postman and it does bring back JSON. What would I need to add to the D3 code for correctly calling the API, to make the visualisation?

d3.json("http://devml1:12800/thesaurus/search?term=[term]&lang=[lang=it?q=road&format=json", function (error, root) {
        if (error) throw error;

Comment: What is the error message you are getting? Might be as simple as a failed authentication..

Comment: d3.v3.min.js:4 Error: Invalid value for <g> attribute transform="translate(NaN,12.5)"

Comment: /thesaurus/search is not a REST endpoint that comes out of the box with MarkLogic. Can you tell more about it? Does the browser dev tools show data is being returned properly? Can you also tell more about how you are using the data to visualize your data?

Comment: The dev tools show that the API is being called and the Network tab does show as successful. However I need to change the node names to the names listed in json from the MarkLogic API. For example the json being called in the examples in d3js.org call a flare.json file with the node names, "name" and "children". The Marklogic API have json naes of "head" and "vars" . What needs to be changed in D3 code to draw head and vars with the nodes for the visualisation. Does that make any sense?

Comment: To summarize, it sounds like the REST call is not returning an error, but just returning data that can't be consumed directly with D3. That is actually a different question. To provide a hint: head/vars sounds like you did a spraql call. That doesn't provide the option to do server-side transform on the output. You can however, just capture and process the json on client-side. Shouldn't be very difficult..